# How to include "Created by..." information (e.g. on the OpenSea listing) on an NFT that you're minting programatically through a smart contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, nft

I've been writing test smart contracts in preparation for a project I'm launching soon. Here is one of the collections created by an example test smart contract: https://opensea.io/collection/quad-tech.

As you'll see, I'm most certainly not an artist, but more importantly I have two issues:

(1) the collection does not have a "Created by Biotechnology" tag in the way that say the Bored Ape Yacht Club collection (https://opensea.io/collection/boredapeyachtclub) has "Created by BoredApeYachtClub".

(2) The NFTs in my Quad.tech collection also don't have "Created by Biotechnology" in their descriptions, the same way that Board Apes have "Created by BoredApeYachtClub" in their NFT descriptions.

Do you know what the issue is here / what code I would need to add to my smart contract to add this "Created by" wording? Here is my smart contract: https://polygonscan.com/address/0x88d108917c172acc19c455da93c1518272f14b02#code

Thanks very much.

Comment: If helpful for anyone, I've had the following response from OpenSea which clears things up for me at least:

A "created by" display appears on a collection/nft that has been safelisted. All collections on OpenSea are discoverable by default, but collections that have been "safelisted" have been approved by our user safety team. If a collection has not been safelisted by our user safety team, potential buyers will be asked to review important collection details and agree to OpenSea’s Terms of Service. Collections become eligible for safelisting review after making their first sale.

Comment: More info here: https://support.opensea.io/hc/en-us/articles/4401938933523-What-is-collection-safelisting-

Comment: the page doesn't seem to be available even when I am logged in. I am told that I am not authorized to view the page

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with your smart contract code. That code is something that is meant to be executed on the Ethereum VM, and has nothing to do with the user interface of the OpenSea website (or any other website for that matter).

I see your NFTs already have some descriptions, like "A particularly lost hamster". You added that at some point when you created this asset/NFT. If you are the owner of this asset, you should be able to change the description of this asset to something like "Created by Biotechnology". If the description itself is part of the asset, then you might need to delete the existing ones and add new assets with desired descriptions.

I cannot see the "Created by BoredApeYachtClub" on their NFTs (must have missed it somehow), but similar applies here as well. I doubt a tag is a part of the asset. It's most likely just a mechanism on the website to filter assets/NFTs. You can simply create this new tag through the UI and tag your NFTs with it. This certainly won't be in the smart contract code.

**Update**:

After additional comments, it is now clear that what you want is to have an account/collection officially verified by OpenSea. Again, this has nothing to do with your smart contract code, but your collection has to become popular enough (reach trading volume of 100 ETH or more on OpenSea and have all collections items revealed) to become eligible for verification. And even then, it can take some time (probably depending on the workload of the team that does the verification) and it's not guaranteed. For more info, refer to the following  page:
https://support.opensea.io/hc/en-us/articles/360063519133-What-is-a-verified-account-or-collection-

Comment: Thank you for the response, Marko. So I can set the description of the collection or the NFT to "Created by Biotechnology" but I'm not sure how to have it so OpenSea does it on its own. The difference being that I can include "Created by Beeple" if I wanted to in the description (and link Beeple's account), doesn't mean it's actually  created by Beeple. When OpenSea adds the "Created by" bit instead then it verifies that that collection/NFT was created by that certain person.

Comment: Just focussing on the collection bit for now - do you know how something like this: https://opensea.io/collection/zodiac-capsules managed to get "Created by CapsuleHouse" on their collection? I would be thrilled if I could even get that kind of tag on my collection.

Comment: Hi Marko - thanks for the response but I'm not looking to have my account/collection officially verified. I don't want the blue tick or anything, all I want is for my collection to show "Created by Biotechnology" - this is different to having it verified. My example in the comment above (opensea.io/collection/zodiac-capsules) is exactly what I'm looking for and they're not verified. Very happy to upvote and mark as accepted if we can manage to work this out! So far I don't think we've solved it though.

Comment: @Simba Sorry but I'm not quite sure about that one. My guess is that either you have missed some personalization of your account in your account settings, or the whole thing is out your hands and this gets added automatically when you become a more prominent account on OpenSea (maybe after the first time someone buys your tokens or something like that). BTW, I have actually answered your original question, you were asking how to get the same as for BoredApeYachtClub what needs to be done in the smart contract. I have answered that, did I not?

Comment: @Simba Then you changed in the comments that you actually want what ZodiacCapsules have, which is not the same. I also noticed that you asked a new question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70696764/how-to-include-created-by-x-information-below-the-name-of-an-opensea-collectio) that specifically refers to ZodiacCapsules. That question should remain opened and wait for someone to answer it properly, but the current question has been answered.