# How to include "Created by X" information below the name of an OpenSea collection

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, cryptocurrency, nft, opensea

I’m building a smart contract but I can't for the life of me work out how to ensure that my collection on OpenSea includes the "Created by X" wording beneath the collection name. Even when I deploy a smart contract that is materially identical to a smart contract that has this tag, it doesn't have the "Created by X" when I deploy it (and so suggests it is not a smart contract issue).

An example project that doesn’t have the “Created by X” bit is this: https://opensea.io/collection/solo-tech. An example project that has the "Created by X" bit is this: https://opensea.io/collection/zodiac-capsules. Any help on why Bored Bunny has the "Created by X" but my project doesn't would be very much appreciated - thank you!

Comment: Please see my updated answer on your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70669842/how-to-include-created-by-information-e-g-on-the-opensea-listing-on-an-n/70692608#70692608

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include "Created by..." information (e.g. on the OpenSea listing) on an NFT that you're minting programatically through a smart contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70669842/how-to-include-created-by-information-e-g-on-the-opensea-listing-on-an-n)

Answer (score 1):

You need at least 1 sale on each collection you wish to have safelisted and you need a Twitter connected that links back to the collection to be verified.

Hope this helps